# Change the template for a new Query in Teradata SQL Assistance

Tags: sql, ide, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I was wondering how I could change the template that is used for creating a new query in SQL assistance?  I have some documentation text I want auto added at the top of every query I write.

Comment: Right click in the query window and "Add to Favorites" plus "View - Show Favorites"?

Comment: Not qutie what I was looking for, but it should wrok for work for my needs.  Thank You!